# Group nodes based on calculation of properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using Neo4j/Cypher, I've got quite a small data set (290 nodes), consisting of only one type of labels (:County).

Their properties looks like this :County( {countyCode, countyName, population}).
There's an index on :County.countyCode

Each :County is related to 1+N other :County by relation :ADJACENT_TO.

What I'm trying to achieve is to find combinations of counties that fit within given values for the population property (say minimum 100000, maximum 120000).

With the query below I've gotten as far as finding pairs, but not combinations of three or more counties.

```
MATCH x = (a:County)-[:ADJACENT_TO]->(b:County)
WHERE reduce(totalPopulation = 0, n IN nodes(x)| totalPopulation + n.population) >= 100000 
AND reduce(totalPopulation = 0, n IN nodes(x)| totalPopulation + n.population) <= 120000
RETURN x, b.countyName, a.countyName, 
reduce(totalPopulation = 0, n IN nodes(x)| totalPopulation + n.population) AS reduction
```

The ultimate goal is to find unique combinations of 1...N counties that falls within the given criteria, i.e. :County(x) is combined with :County(y) and :County(z), but not with :County(w) as that might be connected with :County(v) in a different combination.

No county can exist in a combination where the "core" county is not directly :ADJACENT_TO the given county.

I'd appreciate any answers and pointers to help me on the way.

EDIT:
After a lot of searching I *think* that what I want to achieve is called "Cluster Analysis", but I haven't been able to figure out how to create clusters (what I called groups above), thus analysis is yet a step further away. Maybe that terminology help to clarify what I'm after.

Comment: What is a "core" county? Can you give an example of how you want this grouping to work?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way in just Cypher to generate all possible combinations given an input list, though I did add that as a feature request to APOC procedures. I think the harder part of your request is to limit combinations for one city based upon the combinations used by a different city. That definitely needs either a reexamination, or better requirements defining how that restriction should work. First come first serve?

Comment: Sorry, it's so easy to get blind in your own world. A "core" county would be the county that is adjacent to all other counties in the combination.

Say we have county A, B and C. A is adjacent to both B and C, but B and C are not (necessarily) adjacent to each other. Then A would be the "core" county.

Comment: What max possible value of N?

Comment: There are still a lot of open questions about your use case. For instance: 1) Are there specific criteria for picking the "core" counties, or is the choice arbitrary? 2) Does each "combination" contain 1 and only 1 "core" county? 3) If a non-core county is adjacent to multiple core counties, are there specific rules for picking which combination to put it in? 4) Are you trying to minimize the number of combinations (and maximize the average combination size), or does it not matter?

Comment: What I'm trying to find out is where to open branch-offices and how to define the area for each branch.

As such, each "core" county is where a branch-office could be located. Each branch-office will serve a population between the given limit values.

It's not important whether two "core" counties are adjacent. 

Which counties that are defined as "core" counties would depend on the various combinations that are possible. The goal is to create combinations which are within the limits where as few counties become orphans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I went for was a combination of cypher-queries and PHP-code.

I started with getting all relations between the `:County`-nodes and running a array-permutation in PHP to get possible variations.

From those variations I created `:Cluster`-nodes with `:Contains` relationship to the respective `:Counties`.

I then gave each `:Cluster` a ranking based on the population in the cluster combination.

Then I iterated over the `:Cluster`'s selecting the highest ranked-and-not-previoulsly marked, deleting all other `:Cluster`'s with a `:County` related the the high-ranking `:Cluster`.

So, to conclude - I didn't find a way to query Neo4j with cypher to find the result I wanted-